# Table data formatting ( Data from database)

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

Fetching the array data and using explode i have separated the content. Now, i want  to print those data in the list. But products are printing in the line. I tried using "break tag" And "list tag" Every possible ways.

Here is the code

```
 <tbody id="test">
           @foreach ($data['samplingData'] as $key => $samplingData)
              <tr> <td>{{$samplingData->doctor_name}}</td> 
               <td>{{$samplingData->date}}</td> 
                @foreach(explode(',', $samplingData->products) as $product) 
                    <td> {{$product}} </td>    
                @endforeach

               <td>{{$samplingData->quantity}}</td> </tr>

           @endforeach
         </tbody>
```

Data is printing in this way

```
Name    date      products    quantity
a     12-12-12    a  a  a  a    1 1 1 1
```

I want to print like this

```
Name    date      products    quantity
a      12-12-12     a           1
                    a           1
                    a           1
```

I tried adding tr inside td and as well as list inside the td.

Please help me in formatting the data.

Comment: have u tried `<BR/>` after `{{$product}}` ? `<td> {{$product}} <BR/> </td>`

Comment: Yes I tried. It didn't work. As I have used td. It's printing products in row. I tried creating tr inside td. It still didn't work.

Comment: `<td>@foreach(explode(',', $samplingData->products) as $product) 
                     {{$product}} <BR/>     
                @endforeach</td>`  ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: does it solved your problem?

Comment: Yes. It solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you were creating `<td>` for-each `$product`.

```
 <td>@foreach(explode(',', $samplingData->products) as $product) {{$product}} <BR/> @endforeach</td>
```